# Matrix power relation to prove coefficients exist

Tags: matrices

Let M be a 2x2 Matrix and $n$ an integer $2\geq\ n$. Prove that there exist integers $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $$M^n=a_nM+b_nI$$ To begin, what I did was to use the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem then use a the given relation to find $a_n$ and $b_n$. By the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem $$M^2+c_1M+c_2I=0$$ Here $c_1$ is the negative of the trace and $c_2$ is the determinant. Multiplying throughout by $M^{n-2}$ $$M^n+c_1M^{n-1}+c_2M^{n-2}=0$$ Using the given relation, we can replace the matrix powers $$M(a_{n}+c_1a_{n-1}+c_2a_{n-2})+I(b_{n}+c_1b_{n-1}+c_2b_{n-2})=0$$However this does not imply that the $a_n$ and $b_n$ exist. Any ideas how to proceed with this question?

Comment: Note that, somewhat hiddenly, you are doing induction. If your carry it to the end, you will end up with the solution. You are already very close, you just need to apply the induction hypothesis to the third equation you have written down. But you cannot apply it to $M^n$ yet, because your induction goes only till $n-1$, so...

Comment: @b00nheT Could you explain a bit more, I don't see how I would continue an inductive process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to prove the claim by induction on $n\ge 2$.

As you noticed, because of Cayley Hamilton:
$$M^2+c_1M+c_2I=0\iff M^2=-c_1M-c_2I.$$

But, as the the equation also trivially holds for $n=1$, the induction start holds.

Remark: What I mean to say here, is that you need to check the formula for $n=1$ and $n=2$ for the induction start, as both powers $n-1$ and $n-2$ appear in the formula below, and hence you need both to be able to apply the induction step.

Multiplying the first equation by $M^{n-2}$, we obtain:
$$M^n+c_1M^{n-1}+c_2M^{n-2}=0.$$

But by induction hypothesis, we can rewrite $M^{k}$ as a linear combination of $I,M,$ for any $k\leq n-1.$ Thus
\begin{align*}M^n& =-c_1M^{n-1}-c_2M^{n-2}\\ &=-c_1(aM+bI)-c_2(dM+eI)\\& =-(ac_1+dc_2)M-(c_1b+d_2e)I.
\end{align*}
completing the induction